# How to find Microsoft Office Excel Version on a Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

How can I find the version of MS Excel in a Mac system. I followed this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-version-of-Office-am-I-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19) but I am not sure what version 15.17 corresponds to. Is it MS Office 2013 or MS Office 2016?

[image]

Comment: There was no Office 2013 for Mac. Only 2011 and 2016 (so far), and the link you've provided covers those two versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several places on the Internet that explain which Office version number lines up with which Office product version.  [Wikipedia has a good one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Versions):

```
Office version  Version number
2016 for Mac    15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have MS Office 2016 for Mac despite the copyright info showing 2015 as the date. Any version of MS Office for Mac 15.x will be MS Office 2016. As of June 22, 2016, the current version of MS Excel for Mac 2016 is 15.23.1.